# Firebase .where() in clause return response in same order as array being passed in

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have an array of customer id's that look like so:

```
const customerFinal = [
'1abcadafedafa',
'2eafeafaafaaa',
'3knglaaljdjjj',
'4afnknvknakfn',
'5akfjljjmdmkk',
]
```

I am performing the following query via a firebase function, where I pass the array of ID's above and it grabs all the documents in firestore that correspond to the ID's being passed in:

```
const sourceRef = db.collection('customers').where('id', 'in', customerFinal)
```

the query works as expected, the only issue I'm having is that the order being returned from firebase is not in the same order as the customerFinal array.  Is it possible for firebase to return the corresponding documents in the same order as the customerFinal array?  I have tried sorting, etc. to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firestore documentation for ["in" queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) doesn't make any claims about the sort order of the documents that you receive from that query, so I wouldn't expect them to be sorted in the order that you provide the values.  As such, you should consider sorting the resulting documents in your code, which would not be very expensive in terms of performance (since you can only work with 10 documents at a time).

Comment: The function returns with the following:  Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: order by clause cannot contain a field with an equality filter id, does that mean I'm unable to use id to orderBy or something else at play

Comment: It sounds like you're going to have to sort in your code, then.